# Probability density of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable having the normal density $n(0,\sigma^2)$. Find the density of the random variable $Y = X^2$.
Question: I couldn't figure out why the answers using the following two approaches are different. Did I miss the ½ somewhere?

- Using definition of distribution function:

Since X has normal density $n(0,\sigma^2)$, $X$ has the probability density function:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt (2\pi)} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}} $   $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $G, F$ denote the distribution functions of $X, Y$ respectively. Then
$G(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(X^2 \leq y) = P(-\sqrt y \leq X \leq \sqrt y = F(\sqrt y) - F(-\sqrt y)$.

Differentiate G(y) gives the probability density function $g(y)$:

$g(y) = F'(\sqrt y) - F'(-\sqrt y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt y} (f(\sqrt y) + f(-\sqrt y))$

Thus $g(y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt y}  \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt (2\pi)} e^{-\frac{y}{2\sigma^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2\pi} e^{-\frac{y}{2\sigma^2}} \right) = \frac{e^{-\frac{y}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt(2\pi y)}$

- Using Change of Variable Theorem:

$y = \phi(x) = x^2$ so $\phi^{-1}(x) = \sqrt(y)$

$\frac{d}{dy} \phi^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt y}$

$I = \mathbb{R}$ so $\phi(I) = (0, \infty)$.

Thus $g(y) = f(\phi^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{d}{dy} \phi^{-1}(y) \right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt (2\pi)} e^{-\frac{y}{2\sigma^2}} \left| \frac{1}{2\sqrt y} \right| = \frac{e^{-\frac{y}{2\sigma^2}}}{2\sqrt(2\pi y)}$  $\forall y > 0$.

Comment: The change of variable theorem is for monotone functions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Does the function have to be monotone over the entire real line or over the range of X only? My textbook says the function has to be monotone "on an interval I".

Comment: @AndréNicolas I figured it out. The range of $X$ in this exercise is the entire real line, so the function $\phi(X) = X^2$ is not monotone over the range of $X$. Thanks.

Comment: Usually one can use the method of transformations by splitting things appropriately, in this case by using symmetry and doubling.

Comment: You are welcome. The issue comes up a lot, one is often interested in the distribution of $(X-\mu)^2$.